# Mongoid Many-to-Many Query Returns Not Docs

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm new to Mongo and Mongoid and have a fairly complicated data model where i'm trying to essentially query over a many-to-many relation and not getting any data back even though i've verified the ids seem to match.

The data model is as follows (welcome suggestions if better way to do this):

```
class User  
  has_one :item_list  #favorite items  
  has_one :store_list #favorite stores  

class ItemList  
  belongs_to :user  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items  

class StoreList  
  belongs_to :user  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores  

class Item  
  belongs_to :artist  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :item_lists  

class Store  
  has_many :versions  
  has_and_belongs_to_many :store_lists  

class Version  
  belongs_to :item  
  belongs_to :store
```

On suggestion i read online, am trying to get versions of items on a user's favorites list at a specific store (though left only the specific store part since can't even get across whole list of versions) like so:

```
@favorite_item_ids = current_user.item_list.items.only(:_id).map(&:_id)  
@my_items_here = Version.all_in(item_id: @favorite_item_ids)
```

I'm printing out id, which are as such so should be at least 1 match, but @my_items_here has length 0

@favorite_item_ids
[BSON::ObjectId('4ede1ec254663443fe000011'), ... ]

Version.all.only(:item_id).map(&:item_id)
[BSON::ObjectId('4ede1ec254663443fe000011'), ...]

Appreciate any help!

Versions:
mongoid 2.3.4 gem
mongo 2.0.1
Rails 3.1

Comment: Any update on this? If he answered your question please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
@favorite_item_ids = current_user.item_list.items.distinct(:_id)  
@my_items_here = Version.where(:item_id.in => @favorite_item_ids)
```